# Cannot get code to execute in Electron Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, iframe

I am unable to make code run in an iframe window for a specific application I am building.

Basically, I initially wait for the page to create the iframe using `document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", callback)`. Then, inside of the callback, I look for the event with a target that has a className equivalent to the iframe that I want.

```
if(e.target.className === "child-application") {
        
  const targetIframe = document.querySelector(".child-application");

  console.log("the iframe:", targetIframe);
   // ...
```

I confirm that this is infact the iframe that I want with devtools. It is - it has the content that I want to edit and the place that I want to inject code.

However, upon trying *every* solution I could find on StackOverflow, I am defeated - I *cannot* get code to execute inside of this iframe, or get a style working in it.

I have tried the following methods:

- Creating a script element, popping in the innerHTML of the script I want ran and doing `iframe.contentDocument.head.appendChild(script);`, then trying to use this to inject CSS via the head. This fails because of the security policy, which is fair enough.
- Creating the style element in the parent context and doing `iframe.contentDocument.head.appendChild(style)`. This does nothing - it does not append it, not even when using a timeout of 2s to apply this.

However - doing the latter of these two **DOES** work if I do it in the console! Just not if I do it in a function that runs *with* the webpage. It pops the CSS correctly in the  tag of the iframe and styles whatever the stylesheet tells it to.

Is there something I'm missing? It feels like it's just magically not working for no reason.